# Remove object from vector based on object property

Tags: c++

I want to delete object from vector which has property set on specific value. In this example:

```
void RemoveUser(int val)
{
    users.remove_if([val](User u)
    {
        return u.val == val;
    });
}
```

I can remove specific user based on its `val` property. This works on `std::list`, but its not working on `std::vector`. How can I archieve same result on `vector`?

Comment: std::list has a remove_if member function.  std::vector does not.  You can use the remove_if from <algorithm>.

Answer (score 4):

`std::vector` doesn't have a `remove_if` member. But there is a standard algorith, aptly named `std::remove_if` that can work in tandem with the vectors `erase` member function.

```
users.erase(remove_if(begin(users), end(users), [val](User const& u)
{
    return u.val == val;
}), end(users));
```

First `remove_if` shifts the elements of the range, and returns an iterator past the end of all the "good ones". The vector is of the same size as when we started at this point. Now that iterator is fed to `erase`, which kills all of those items, from that "new end", to the "old end" of the vector.

The reason `std::list` implements its own member version of `remove_if` is to better utilize its node based structure. It doesn't have to do copies to shift elements around or delete them. For `std::vector`, the algorithm is the best we can do.

Comment: It is an important distinction. I've seen code that does stuff like call `delete` on the "bad" elements after a call to `remove_if`.

Comment: @juanchopanza - That implies the code was using raw pointers as owning handles. I think misunderstanding `remove_if` was the least of the problems there.

Comment: Sigh. OK, then take the bad elements to do anything else with their value. Remove tables from a database or whatever.

Comment: @juanchopanza - No need for dramatics. Already reworded given how sticky a point it is. If the vectors elements don't tidy after themselves when moved, don't go blaming algorithms that assume value semantics.